# 誤訳: 「case-insensitive」が「大文字と小文字が区別されます」と訳されている

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

[Markdown ヘルプのリンクについての説明](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links)が

> リンク定義の名前 [1] および [yahoo] は任意の一意の文字列を使用でき、大文字と小文字が区別されます。[yahoo] は、
>   [YAHOO] と同じです。

となっており、矛盾しています。本家ではcase-insensitiveとなっていることと、また実際の機能から言って、例えば「大文字と小文字は区別**されません**」とするのが正しいと思われます。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

変更が完了いたしました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ストリングはこちら -> https://ja.traducir.win/string/3516